# AdS/CFT correspondence

Tags: quantum-gravity, ads-cft

Can the AdS/CFT correspondence, which states that the anti-de Sitter space in $n$ dimensions is equivalent to a Conformal Field Theory in $n-1$ dimensions, for quantum gravity be seen as an analogue model, which means that two models describe similar physics?

Comment: What is an analogue model?

Comment: See https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.12942/lrr-2011-3.pdf

Comment: Please put in all the relevant details in the question above. I am not going to read through a 159 page document in order to answer your question.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question. I mean, for example, black holes horizon and horizons in other systems like fluids....

Comment: Oh ok! Thank you for your answer. If you post an answer, I can accept it. Sorry for the misconception on my side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CFT model is not an analogue of the bulk quantum gravity. Rather, they are literally the SAME theory. That is the point of AdS/CFT. QG in AdS is the exact same thing as a CFT in one lower dimension. No analogies needed here.